# Blank page using multiple views with UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I followed this [article](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) and this [other](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router) I've tried to replicate what's on the wiki, without any luck.

So far this is what I've done
the folder structure:

- partial

  - index

    - index.html // inner view
    - index.css
    - index.js //controller
  - footer

    - footer.html
    - footer.js
  - header

    - // same structure
- index.html // main file

stateProvider:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("index",
        {
            url: "/index",
            templateUrl:'/partial/index.html',
            views: {
                'footer@index': {
                    templateUrl: "/partial/header.html",
                    controller:"FooterCtrl"
                },
                'header@index': {
                    templateUrl: "/partial/header.html",
                    controller: "HeaderCtrl"
                }
            }
    });  
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
```

**EDIT:**

this is the markup:

```
<div>
    <div id="content" class="container">

        <div ui-view="header"></div>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <div ui-view="footer"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

the url I'm browsing is: localhost:9001/#/index

I don't get any error just a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you used incorrect paths on the templateUrl.

Here's the plunker using ui-router: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nqwlkq1vGh5VTBid4sMv?p=preview

I also suggest reading the source code of http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/ it has an abstract implementation here and many comments on how to work with ui-router properly.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I noticed that I was getting 404 errors that fixed them but I'm still getting a blank page

Comment: Ok i'm guessing you that you're missing the ui-view directives on your markup? can you add your markup there?

Comment: I've updated the markup, let's say that I guess that the ui-view in blank will be loaded because of the 'route'

Comment: Read more about the ui-router sample it helped me alot when dealing with the ui-views. :) np

Answer (score 0):

don't left a slash at the end of the url

not working:
http://sjhite.com/questions/23924587**/**

working:
http://sijhte.com/questions/23924587